# Dynamic object creation inside another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this in constructor

```
this.state = {
  inputs : {}
}
```

This in handleInputChange (triggered on blur of input)

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      inputs[name]: value
    });
  }
```

So that my state will look like

```
inputs : { name1 : "text1", "name2": "text2" }
```

I am getting this syntax error

```
 Unexpected token, expected , (20:12)

this.setState({
> 20 |       inputs[name]: value
     |             ^
  21 |     });
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing an Object literal, pass a reference to an object instead.

With this you can add a computed (or semi-computed) property to the Object before passing it.

```js
handleInputChange(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.value;
  const name = target.name;
  let state = {inputs: this.state.inputs};
  state.inputs[name] = value

  this.setState(state);
}
```

Comment: this.state already has a object `inputs`. I want all the new `key:value` pairs inside that. like `inputs : { name1 : "text1", "name2": "text2" }`

Answer (score 3):

```
handleInputChange(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.value;
  const name = target.name;
  let updatedInputs = this.state.inputs;
  updatedInputs[name]= value;
  this.setState({
    inputs: updatedInputs
  });
}
```

Comment: this worked, we just need to declare updateInputs, else its throwing error. +1

Answer (score 1):

While the above will work, it's better to manage state in a bunch of 'smaller' properties than in one big object. The reason is everything that depends on the top level state property (i.e. inputs) updates every time it changes. If you make each input it's own property directly in state, you'll have less to update, and it should be faster.(It might not be noticeable for this case.)

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({name: value});
}
```

Comment: Thats a good, but in this case I have few other info in state and for saving form data I just need to serialize `inputs` and send it via post

Answer (score 0):

I believe the is problem is the `inputs` variable is not initiated.

this should work

```
handleInputChange(event) {
const target = event.target;
const value = target.value;
const name = target.name;
let inputs = {}
this.setState({
  inputs[name]: value
});
```

}

Comment: inputs is initialized, please see my constructor.